# Expression for "repeat placement in storage" or "conditioning for storage"

Tags: terminology, translation, phrase-requests

From a [Russian National Standard for medical equipment](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200134141):

> 8.1.5. Маркировка потребительской тары или футляров должна содержать:
>   - год и месяц **переконсервации** при необходимости;

i.e., "The labeling on consumer packaging or cases should contain:
- the year and the month of **re-preservation**, if necessary;"

What would be a natural-sounding English phrase for **re-preservation**? The term means that this piece of equipment had been for some reason withdrawn from its packaging and maybe even used for its intended purpose or tested, but then was again put into the proper condition for storage (greased with corrossion protection grease, maybe) and packed into its consumer packaging, to be ready for long-term storage, shipment or sale.

It was "twice preserved", so to speak. The Multitran dictionary offers some options for **[переконсервация](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&langlist=1)**, but they might be hard to understand to the native speaker of English.

Comment: M... yes, although no dictionary seems to defined the prefixed word "represervation," the term is indeed in use in formal writing.

Comment: As in "When it is determined that the limit of preservation effectiveness has been reached, the interval covered between initial preservation and subsequent **represervation** shall be established as the continuing exercising and **represervation cycle** for that installation." (emphasis mine) **4.6.1.1** MIL-STD-952, 30 Nov 1971, US DoD books.google.co.in/… vehicles" (Google Books) p.13: https://books.google.com/books?id=GA_eTGkJ7LEC&&q=%22nondeteriorated

Comment: @Kris - ah, great! I thought it was Russian coinage. Now I can leave "represervation" there without worrying about its correctness.

Comment: If we label such items as REFURBISHED, and stored accordingly, will it work?  Refurbish = to repair and clean equipment so that its condition is like new:
The company, which refurbishes computers, printers, and cell phones, has continued to see growth throughout 2010.https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refurbish.  Xerox India (where I worked) always used the word 'Refurbished copiers'.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You might try ***Resealed***.  Or ***Factory Resealed***.

The term implies a piece of equipment has been opened and prepared or tested before being repackaged and quality assured.

Answer (score 1):

The term is *Repackaged*.

It has been removed from the packaging and after some essential process put back into the package. The Geni back in the bottle.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, it is "double preservation"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I believe the word you're looking for is "**refurbished**."

When items have been sold, used, returned for whatever reason, restored to like-new condition, repackaged in fresh packaging, and put up for sale as being as good as new, usually for a discount, the word used to describe such items on packaging and in ads is "refurbished," like I can buy a brand-new iPhone 12 from Apple for $1,100, but I can buy a *refurbished* iPhone 12 from Apple for only $750, both having the exact same warranty and each identical to the other, only the "refurbished" one was previously sold, used, returned (possibly due to defect), repaired and/or restored to like-new condition, and then repackaged in fresh packaging to be sold as a "[refurbished](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/refurb)" unit or a "[refurb](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/refurb)."